# What is the AWS SDK API for adding a Resource-based policy to a Lambda function in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I wasn't able to find it, Googling far and wide... I tried using `Amazon.Lambda.AmazonLambdaClient`, `Amazon.IdentityManagement.AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient` and other APIs with no luck.

I am able to read the policy using `var policy = await lambdaClient.GetPolicyAsync(new GetPolicyRequest{FunctionName = "my-lambda" });`, but not change it.

In AWS Console, that's the page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AddPermission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_AddPermission.html)

> Grants an AWS service or another account permission to use a function. You can apply the policy at the function level, or specify a qualifier to restrict access to a single version or alias. If you use a qualifier, the invoker must use the full Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of that version or alias to invoke the function

[Granting function access to AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html#permissions-resource-serviceinvoke)

[To grant Amazon S3 permission to invoke a function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#addPermission-property)

```js
 var params = {
  Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction", 
  FunctionName: "my-function", 
  Principal: "s3.amazonaws.com", 
  SourceAccount: "123456789012", 
  SourceArn: "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-1xpuxmplzrlbh/*", 
  StatementId: "s3"
 };
 lambda.addPermission(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    Statement: "{\"Sid\":\"s3\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":\"s3.amazonaws.com\"},\"Action\":\"lambda:InvokeFunction\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function\",\"Condition\":{\"StringEquals\":{\"AWS:SourceAccount\":\"123456789012\"},\"ArnLike\":{\"AWS:SourceArn\":\"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-1xpuxmplzrlbh\"}}}"
   }
   */
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, found it in C# too - it's: `new Amazon.Lambda.AmazonLambdaClient().AddPermissionAsync(new AddPermissionRequest{...})`